# Evidence of return following a visit to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration

What are the best sorts of evidence of return following a visit to the UK to provide when applying for a visa ? Apart from employer letter

Comment: A prior return? From an earlier visit?  What kind of visa application requires evidence of return?

Comment: Return to home country/country of residence surely?

Comment: @GayotFow I think we're looking for evidence of intention to return from the visit for which the visa is sought.

Comment: Evidence to return home when applying for a visit visa. In other terms , how to show an individual's ties to his home country ?

Comment: @SamanAhmed There are multiple queries on this website for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You are preparing an application for entry clearance and want to preload it with strong evidence of returnability.  There are several really great ways to accomplish this...

1. **Evidence of strong social and economic ties**: most people who are successful applicants accomplish this through their bank statements. We already have a question/answer about this at [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) Essentially, the decision-maker examines your cash flows and deduces that (a) that you have the capacity for travel and (b) that your apparent lifestyle is stable.
2. **Evidence of peripatetic activity**: they love to see where the applicant has a long history of travel to the USA, Europe, and the affluent Commonwealth. This sort of history can overcome almost any deficiency, including weak financial circumstances. They love this sort of thing; they eat it up.  Peripatetic activity acts like a universal panacea for people with visa problems.
3. **Performance history**: they like it if the applicant has visited the UK over the course of say, a decade without performance issues like overstaying. The best case is when the applicant has been visiting the UK off and on for most of their life.
4. **Less obvious ways**: there are some less obvious ways to show returnability, like having had diplomatic credentials or holding elected office.

Sometimes having a spouse and dependents at home can be helpful, but it is not always the great cure it's touted to be. This is especially true if the applicant is low-skilled or in a [blue collar profession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-collar_worker) where they can work illegally and make foreign remittances. While I mention low-skilled, it can also hold true for physicians and nurses who can work illegally and make foreign remittances; we see a lot of [PLAB refusals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=plab) on this site for reasons like that.

As a side-note, it may be fruitful to consider the flip side: what things about me are likely to show that I am a high-risk applicant?  You may be able to benefit by giving equal consideration to those also.